# Should ofy().consistency(Consistency.STRONG).load().type(this.getEntityClass()).count() always return the correct result?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

My experience suggests that...

```
ofy().consistency(Consistency.STRONG).load().type(this.getEntityClass()).count()
```

...immediately after an insert (in another request) doesn't always return the updated count. Is there something I can do to to force it to, even at a greater performance cost?

Note: I understand the performance limitations inherent in counting like this, but in my case, correctness is more important than speed.

Comment: The documentation says _Queries without an ancestor() restriction are always weakly consistent_. I had taken that as "at least by default", but something tells me this is a caveat of the datastore. Edit: Confirmed. Will answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries):

> Queries without an ancestor filter only return eventually consistent results.